# How to convert/parse raw html to wp gutenberg blocks using wp-blocks api?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I'm have a difficult with preparing my post data for importing it to the site. I'm want to convert all my raw html to gutenberg ready blocks (like `<!--wp:paragraph--> <p>hello world</p> <!--/wp:paragraph-->` ) to avoid manually transformation for each post. What happening now:

Register a handler srcipt and dependencies - `wp_enqueue_script( 'filter', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/article-filter.js', array('jquery', 'wp-blocks', 'wp-element'));`

Calling rawHandler/pasteHandler - 
`var gutblock = wp.blocks.rawHandler({ 
    HTML: '<p class="content">Hello world </p>' 
});`

Get error - `Cannot read property 'attributes' of undefined`
Maybe i'm something misunderstood in main concept or do something wrong.

Will be very appreciated for help.

Answer (score 3):

There are is a small helper function that firstly convert raw HTML to gutenberg blocks and then serialize it to gutenberg-ready post content.

Enquire script

```
function load_admin_resources_footer() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'filter', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/article-filter.js', array('jquery', 'wp-blocks', 'wp-edit-post'));
}
add_action('admin_footer', 'load_admin_resources_footer');
```

Converting to blocks

```
var editholdy_is_activate = false;
function convert_to_gutenberg(content, remove_spaces = false) { // "'wp-blocks', 'wp-edit-post'" - should be setted as current script dependecies

    // initiate all built-in gutenberg blocks
    if (!editholdy_is_activate) {
        $('<div />').attr('id', 'editholdy').attr('style', 'display: none').appendTo('body');
            wp.editPost.initializeEditor('editholdy');
            editholdy_is_activate = true;
    }

    var gutblock = wp.blocks.rawHandler({ 
        HTML:  content,
    });

    var serelized = wp.blocks.serialize(gutblock);
    serelized = (remove_spaces) ? serelized.replace(/(\n|\r)/g, '') : serelized;

    return serelized;

}
```

Comment: DiFox, any further explanation needed? Like what do you actually do once you enqueue this script?